# Closed subspace of weighted L2 space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $L_{w_{\xi}}^{2}[0,\infty)$ be a [weighted $L^2$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weighted_Lp_spaces) with weight function $w_{\xi}(x) = \frac{\exp\left({-(x+\xi)^3}\right)}{(x + \xi)^2},\; \xi > 0$ and let $T$ denote the operator that satisfies $(Tf)(x) = f(2x)$.

I want to know the topological properties of the set $$A:= \{ f \in L_{w_{\xi}}^{2}[0,\infty)\;| \;\|Tf\| \leq \|f\| \}$$

Especially if it is closed or if it is a subspace. Closedness would be easy if $T$ was bounded, but I doubt that this is true. Also I doubt that this set is a subspace, but I couldnt find a counterexample either.